# phpMyAdmin stores but does not read config

Tags: phpmyadmin, config

Found out I can reconfigure the PMA UI (version 5.0.1 in my case; I want no database grouping, no pagination of tables, and a search quick link); but the settings get lost everytime I log out.

I found [an article on techrepublic](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-enable-phpmyadmin-configuration-storage-to-gain-more-options-and-security/), which can be cut down to three lines:

- create a database `users`
- create any table with any fields
- import `sql/create_tables.sql` from phpMyAdmin directory

After a partial import (omitting the create database and use `phpmyadmin`), the warning about impermanent settings is gone and the settings are now stored in `users`.`pma__userconfig`. But they don´t seem to be read. I change the settings, I log out, log back in, and the UI is back to default config.

I would like a hint on what to do so they get read; but I am ready to hardwire them if I must (though I could use some directions for that, too).

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of possible answers to your question. You could just edit the configuration file directly, or if you prefer to use the graphical interface to change settings then you do need to create the Configuration Storage database.

### Configuration file

The main source of configuration directives are the phpMyAdmin configuration file, `config.inc.php`. That file is normally in the same directory as phpMyAdmin (you have to create it or copy `config.sample.inc.php` as a security precaution), but in most Linux packages the maintainer puts the file in `/etc/phpmyadmin/`. You can edit that file by hand; to achieve the settings you've mentioned the file probably would look like this:

```
<?php
$cfg['NavigationTreeEnableGrouping'] = false;
$cfg['FirstLevelNavigationItems'] = 9999;
$cfg['MaxNavigationItems'] = 9999;
```

I'm not immediately sure what you mean by "a search quick link" unless you're referring to the [saved search feature](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_savedsearches) (which does require the configuration storage database).

### Graphical settings

In addition to the configuration file, phpMyAdmin also is able to store some configuration directives in the database. This can be handy for some users who prefer to graphically see the options available or in shared server situations where multiple people use the same phpMyAdmin installation and wish to have their own preferences.

However, that article is pretty wrong in some ways and quite confusing. A better source would be [the official documentation](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#manual-configuration). You've already discovered that the article tells people to import the file in to the `users` database but the file forces the `phpmyadmin` name (which users like yourself are, of course, welcome to edit). However, it misses a part about modifying the expected database and table names in the configuration file. In the case of the article, it tells people to create the `users` database, imports the file to `phpmyadmin` anyway, and then phpMyAdmin automatically detects and uses the `phpmyadmin` database anyway. I don't see why the article objects to the `phpmyadmin` database in the first place, but the key step missed in the article is changing the expected names in the configuration file.

### Fixing it

Now, you probably don't really care about any of that and just want your phpMyAdmin working. As I mentioned, one option is to edit `config.inc.php`, but to use the graphical settings tool, you basically need to either use the default database name (phpmyadmin) or edit `config.inc.php` and tell it explicitly what settings to use to connect.

At a minimum, if you use the 'users' database, you should add this line to config.inc.php (I'll mention again that I see no reason to use 'users' over 'phpmyadmin' which shouldn't require any additional configuration).

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'users';
```

There's more to this, such as the suggestion to create a controluser for the best compatibility with multiuser installations, or manually specifying the table names, but I've already gone on for much too long. I'm happy to help if you have further questions about this, though.

### Recap

To review, you have three options: put the directives directly in `config.inc.php` and skip creating any database or graphical configuration, use the database name `phpmyadmin` instead of `users`, or add the pmadb line to `config.inc.php` to tell phpMyAdmin you're using a non-standard database name. I suggest the second option.